# Binding a simple list in dart web components won't work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

1. I downloaded DartEditor
2. I created a new web components project with the click-counter example
3. I have made some modifications

Added custom component, list-select:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('list-select')
class ListSelect extends PolymerElement {

  List<String> intls = const ["enUS", "nlNL"];

  ListSelect.created() : super.created();
}
```

with html

```dart
<polymer-element name="list-select">
  <template>
    <style>

    </style>
    <div>
      <select>
        <option template iterate="item in intls">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="list-select.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

in {{myappname}}.html, I added two lines:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="list-select.html">
```

and

```dart
<list-select></list-select>
```

However, my select stays empty. What do I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `iterate` in Polymer and the `{{}}` are missing.

```dart
<option template iterate="item in intls">{{item}}</option>
```

should be

```dart
<template repeat="{{item in intls}}"
  <option >{{item}}</option>
</template>
```

There are a few elements (for example `<tr>`) which don't allow other elements like `<template>` inside them on some browsers.
A supported workaround is to add the `template repeat` attributes.

```dart
<tr template repeat="{{item in intls}}"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
```

But normally you use a `<template>` tag for `repeat` and `if`.

Comment: Awesome, this did it. However, https://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/#observing-collections says no curly braces are needed.

Comment: Web-UI is old and busted (the predecessor of Polymer.dart). For information about Polymer see https://www.polymer-project.org and https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/